# Is this kind of chaining possible in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, chaining

I'm working on a file manager framework similar to [elFinder](http://elfinder.org/). My current code works fine but now I want to make it look better and add chaining (I'm not sure if it's chaining or decorator pattern).

Here is a sample of what I want to do:

```
function UI() {}

UI.prototype.folders = function(){
    return [];
}

UI.prototype.folders.prototype.getSelectedFolder = function(){
   return {};
}
```

Calling `UI.folders()` should return an array of folder objects. So if you call `UI.folders()` you would get something similar to this:

```
[
    Object { name="folder1", selected=false }, 
    Object { name="folder2", selected=false }, 
    Object { name="folder3", selected=true }
]
```

And calling `UI.folders().getSelectedFolder()` would filter the results from `UI.folders()` and will return:

```
Object { name="folder3", selected=true }
```

Is this possible? Is it right to say "chaining" in this case or it's "decorative pattern"? 
If it's not - is there another more appropriate way to do it?

Any help wold be really appreciated!

Comment: You're not doing inheritance correctly. The `...folders.prototype.getSelectedFolder` will have no benefit because the `UI.prototype.folders` just returns a plain Array. for the `folders.prototype` to have an effect, you need to invoke `folders` as a constructor, and have it return the object being constructed instead of an Array.

Comment: ...but yes, implemented correctly, `UI.folders().getSelectedFolder()` is an example of method chaining.

Comment: +1 I'm not sure why the down vote, it's not only a good descriptive question but you included what you tried to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The are a few different ways to solve this.  The primary goal is that when you call a function you get an object/function back that is the same type of object with different properties.  I'm not a fan of the prototype usage so I would do it like this (this is one way to solve it):

```
var FolderList = function ()
{
    var _folders = [];
    folders.pop({ name: "folder1", selected: false });
    folders.pop({ name: "folder2", selected: true });
    folders.pop({ name: "folder3", selected: false });

    // prevent other programers from changing _folders
    // which would break this, so just use a function
    this.folders = function ()
    {
        return _folders;
    }

    this.selectedFolders = function ()
    {
        var tmpFolders = [];
        for (var folderIndex = 0; 
             folderIndex < this._folders.length; 
             folderIndex++)
        {
            if (this._folders[folderIndex].selected)
            {
                tmpFolders.pop(_folders[folderIndex]);
            }
        }
        _folders = tmpFolders;
        return this;
    }

    this.addFolder = function (folder)
    {
        _folders.pop(folder);
        return this;
    }
};

var folderList = new FolderList();
folderList.selectedFolders()
          .addFolder({ name: "folder1", selected: false })
          .addFolder({ name: "folder3", selected: true })
          .selectedFolders();

// array of 2 objects, folder2 and folder3
var arrayOfSelectedFolder = folderList.folders();
```

Comment: Thanks for the code! Using parts of your code I figured it out :)

Answer (score 2):

The code in your question isn't reflective of a proper implementation, but to answer your direct questions, yes, this...

```
UI.folders().getSelectedFolder()
```

...would be an example of method chaining.

---

A decorator pattern is different. If you have a set of methods, and each one should always first invoke some common function, you can create a decorator that will return a function that first calls the common one, then the actual one...

```
function foo() {
    console.log('I\'m foo, and I\'m first, and I was given these args:', arguments);
}

function decorateWithFoo(decorated) {
    return function () {
        foo.apply(this, arguments);
        decorated.apply(this, arguments);
    };
}
```

---

So you can use `decorateWithFoo` to create a function that always invokes `foo` first...

```
  // create and decorate bar()
var bar = function(a,b) {
    console.log('I\'m bar, and I was called after "foo", and was given args:', a, b);
};
bar = decorateWithFoo(bar);

bar(123, 456); // this will first call `foo()`, then (the original) `bar()`.
```

---

```
  // create and decorate baz()
var baz = function(a,b) {
    console.log('I\'m baz, and I was called after "foo", and was given args:', a, b);
};
baz = decorateWithFoo(baz);

baz(123, 456); // this will first call `foo()`, then (the original) `baz()`.
```

Some languages have built in syntax for creating decorators. JavaScript currently does not.

---

If you find yourself using decorators in different ways, you could create another function that sets up the initial decorator function...

```
function generateDecorator(decorator) {
    return function (decorated) {
        return function () {
            decorator.apply(this, arguments);
            decorated.apply(this, arguments);
        };
    };
}
```

So our original `decoreateWithFoo` could have been set up like this...

```
function foo() {
    console.log('I\'m foo, and I\'m first, and I was given these args:', arguments);
}

var decorateWithFoo = generateDecorator(foo);
```

Answer (score 1):

To make this work properly, you need to make your folders method be a function that returns an object that inherits from an array.:

```
UI.prototype.folders = function(){
    // must return an object that inherits from an array
    // that has the additional methods on it you want like getSelectedFolder()
}
```